# Current / power measurement using ACS71020

Tags: current-measurement, power-measurement, allegro

I am having some hard time in understanding and comprehending the value for ACS71020 current and power measurement. In the manual, rms_avg_1 and rms_avg_2 has been mentioned stating that "The
combination of the two accumulator allows the user to select how long to average for as well as how often the values are updated. The exact time this averages over depends on n (the number of
samples per cycle)". if I choose rms_avg_1 = 120 , wouldn't this be taking average of 120 rms values (hence averaging over 1 sec , given 60 Hz frequency and rms calculation done every half cycle). what is significance for rms_avg_2 ?? Can somebody help on this.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Where's the link to the manual? What page are you talking about?

Comment: Here is the link to the manual "https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/1304272/Allegro/ACS71020/1" , I am talking about page 14

Comment: Basically ACS71020 provides two averaging stages. The first stage is to get the average of raw data. The second stage is to get the average of the first average, a.k.a average of average.